# Lua module for calculating the molar mass of chemical compounds

Tags: math, lua, mediawiki

I have been using (or attempting to, most of the modules I have I have borrowed from other Wikis as my understanding of Lua is limited at best) Lua-based modules and their invoking templates (i.e., the ones that invoke them with `{{#invoke:}}`) on my Wiki for some time and I have an infobox for chemical compounds (my *Chembox*) which includes inputs for the numbers of atoms of each chemical element present in the compound (i.e., those numbers used in the compound's *molecular formula*) and the molar mass of the compound. I was thinking, since it is possible to calculate the molar mass of the compound based on its molecular formula it might be possible to create a Lua module that can do this automatically for me, eliminating the need for me to input the molar mass myself into these infoboxes.

So my question is basically, how do I do this?

### Research

My background is in mathematics, so I felt the most straight-forward way of doing this is to set up two vectors, A and B, and perform a dot-product between them. A would contain the user-defined variables, namely, those provided to the template that invokes the module. For example, say we were talking about ethanol (C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub>O) then the template may look like:

```
{{Molar mass calculator
|C = 2
|H = 6
|O = 1
}}
```

. B would contain the average atomic mass of each element in grams per mol (g/mol). This vector will be self-provided (i.e., by me, I have a list of 84 elements found in sufficient quantities in nature for these standard atomic weights to be available, with their standard atomic weights also listed. So I will provide them in the Lua code if you just show me where to add them to the code.).

I have looked up dot products in Lua to see if this is possible and how to do them and found this code (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dot_product#Lua):

```
function dotprod(a, b)
  local ret = 0
  for i = 1, #a do
    ret = ret + a[i] * b[i]
  end
  return ret
end

print(dotprod({1, 3, -5}, {4, -2, 1}))
```

Comment: May I ask why the downvotes? If there's something I can improve I will gladly do it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking; what do you want the code to do, look up the molar mass for each element?

Comment: No, I will provide those molar masses. Sorry for the lack of clarity, I will add some info on this to the question.

Comment: What will the user input look like?

Comment: I thought I already answered that, when I gave the ethanol template example?

Comment: Ah, that is what that is for. OK, I understand what you need now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via emailing the Wikitech-I mailing list (wikitech-I@lists.sourceforge.net) I received an answer. *Module:Molar mass calculator* is to have the code (the round function is designed to round the end result to the nearest three decimal places, as I later decided that I wanted this capability too):

```
local p = {};

function p.calc(frame)
    local atomicWeights = mw.loadData(  'Module:Standard atomic weight'  )
    local total = 0

    for element, quantity in pairs( frame:getParent().args ) do
        if quantity ~= "" then
            local atomicWeight = atomicWeights[element] or error( 'Element "' .. element .. '" is not known. Please add it to [[Module:Standard atomic weight]] if it\'s not a typo.' )
            quantity = tonumber( quantity ) or error( 'Quantity for ' .. element .. ' is not a number.' )
            total = total + atomicWeight * quantity
        end
    end

    function round(num, idp)
        local mult = 10^(idp or 0)
        return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
    end

    return round(total,3)
end

return p
```

*Module:Standard atomic weight* has the code:

```
local  M =  {}

M['Ag']  =  107.8682      -- Silver (Ag)
M['As']  =  74.921595     -- Arsenic (As)
M['Au']  =  196.966569    -- Gold (Au)
M['B']   =  10.8135       -- Boron (B)
M['Ba']  =  137.327       -- Barium (Ba)
M['Bi']  =  208.9804      -- Bismuth (Bi)
M['Br']  =  79.904        -- Bromine (Br)
M['C']   =  12.0106       -- Carbon (C)
M['Ca']  =  40.078        -- Calcium (Ca)
M['Cl']  =  35.4515       -- Chlorine (Cl)
M['Co']  =  58.933194     -- Cobalt (Co)
M['Cu']  =  63.546        -- Copper (Cu)
M['F']   =  18.998403163  -- Fluorine (F)
M['Fe']  =  55.845        -- Iron (Fe)
M['Ga']  =  69.723        -- Gallium (Ga)
M['H']   =  1.007975      -- Hydrogen (H)
M['Hg']  =  200.592       -- Mercury (Hg)
M['I']   =  126.90447     -- Iodine (I)
M['K']   =  39.0983       -- Potassium (K)
M['Li']  =  6.9675        -- Lithium (Li)
M['Mg']  =  24.3055       -- Magnesium (Mg)
M['Mn']  =  54.938044     -- Manganese (Mn)
M['N']   =  14.006855     -- Nitrogen (N)
M['Na']  =  22.98976928   -- Sodium (Na)
M['Ni']  =  58.6934       -- Nickel (Ni)
M['O']   =  15.9994       -- Oxygen (O)
M['P']   =  30.973761998  -- Phosphorus (P)
M['Pb']  =  207.2         -- Lead (Pb)
M['Pt']  =  195.084       -- Platinum (Pt)
M['S']   =  32.0675       -- Sulfur (S)
M['Se']  =  78.971        -- Selenium (Se)
M['Sr']  =  87.62         -- Strontium (Sr)
M['Tl']  =  204.3835      -- Thallium (Tl)
M['Zn']  =  65.38         -- Zinc (Zn)

return  M
```

and *Template:Molar mass calculator*:

```
{{#invoke:Molar mass calculator|calc}} g/mol
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for :)

Populate the "AtomicWeightLookup" table with your own values.

There is an example call to the "Calculate" function at the end of the program.

```
local AtomicWeightLookup = {
 C = 12.01,
 H = 1.001,
 O = 16
}

local function Calculate(Input)
 -- Input Example: {C = 2, H = 6, O = 1}
 local Result = 0
 -- Iterate through Input table
 for Element,Quantity in next,Input do
  -- If element is not found in table, assume 0 weight.
  local AtomicWeight = AtomicWeightLookup[Element] or 0
  -- Multiply
  Result = Result + Quantity * AtomicWeight
 end
 return Result
end

-- EXAMPLE
print(Calculate({C = 2, H = 6, O = 1}))
```

Comment: Um, the problem is if I'm not mistaken this code doesn't take any input given to the template . i.e. {{Molar mass calculator|C=3|H=8|O=2}} would give the same output as {{Molar mass calculator|C=2|H=6|O=1}} if this code is used as Module:Molar mass calculator (and Template:Molar mass calculator is {{#invoke:Molar mass calculator}}), because all the edits made to user-provided variable MUST be made to the Lua script.

Comment: I don't have any experience with MediaWiki's templates. It looks like all you would have to do is stick this function into a table (according to their example), grab the user's input and put it into this function. How does MediaWiki pass parameters to the function? If you use C=2|H=6|O=1, does MediaWiki pass it as a table or a tuple?

Comment: Not a clue, I understand wikitext to some extent, but I don't know Lua.

Comment: Well, I provided the Lua code -- all you have to do is port it into MediaWiki. I don't think I will be able to help you from here; best of luck!